# Recursive CTE assistance

Tags: sql, t-sql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

I'm no expert on SQL and can do simple joins and Union queries, what I'm trying to do is produce an extract of a Orders that relate to each other. I believe I can use a Recursive CTE to get the extract required.

The current process is if an order is to be amended then the original transaction is cancelled and a new order created. Both orders have different Order id's which are the primary key. You could potentially have the scenario that an order is emended x amount of times. The "x" is completely variable.

The order details are contained in Table A1. Order_ID is the primary key
The way orders are related to each other are in Table A2. Order_ID is the new order, Parent_Order_ID is the original order.

So far I have the following

```
WITH DT_TEST AS(
    select * from 
    A1 inner join A1 on A1.Order_Id = b.Parent_Order_Id
)
SELECT * FROM DT_TEST
```

I know I need to do a Union with an Anchor but don't know what I syntax I need, If someone can point me in the correct direction. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

We can phrase a recursive CTE in SQL Server as a union between a base query and a recursive query.  The possibly tricky part is in the recursive query, which consists of a join of the base table to the CTE itself.  Note that the join condition is that a given `Parent_Order_Id` in the base table matches to some `Order_Id` in the preceding CTE.

```
WITH DT_TEST AS (
    -- base query
    SELECT Order_Id, Parent_Order_Id
    FROM A1
    WHERE Parent_Order_Id IS NULL
    UNION ALL 
    -- recursive query
    SELECT a.Order_Id, a.Parent_Order_Id
    FROM A1 a
    INNER JOIN DT_TEST b
        ON a.Parent_Order_Id = b.Order_Id
)

SELECT * FROM DT_TEST;
```